# LINQ, to check if this characters contains in my some tables in my DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

```
var unos = new List<string> { "W", "w" };

var pesme = _entities.Tracks.Where(x => unos.Contains(x.Name) || unos.Contains(x.Genre.Name) || unos.Contains(x.Album.Title) || unos.Contains(x.Album.Artist.Name)).ToList();

   foreach (var p in pesme) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name}-{p.Album.Title}-{p.Album.Artist.Name}-{p.Genre.Name}");
            }
```

Comment: what is wrong with this code? where do you stuck in?

Comment: it shows that is empty, but I know to have a track that contains w or W. There is no result in console and when i put breakpoint, var pesme is null.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to check `Name` contains `W` or `w`. But now you are checking `W` contains `x.Name`!!

Try this one:

```
var unos = new List<string> { "W", "w" };
    
var pesme = _entities.Tracks.ToList().Where(x => unos.Any(t=> x.Name.Contains(t) || x.Genre.Name.Contains(t) /* rest of conditions*/ )).ToList();
    
foreach (var p in pesme) {
      Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name}-{p.Album.Title}-{p.Album.Artist.Name}-{p.Genre.Name}");
                }
```